# Change decimal separator in windows xp with php 5.3 and oracle 10g

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g, windows-xp, nls

I have two computers :

Server :

- Centos.

PC Developer:

- windows xp

Both:

- apache
- php 5.3
- connection with the same BD.

My table has a number column. When I print the number column in php, the output is :

Server :

```
12.244
12.890
```

Pc Developer

```
12,244
12,890
```

I want that the pc developer to print dot as decimal separator, but I don't know how to do it.

Both have the same configuration in php.ini ( datatimezone ) and in the pc developer , the default configuration for decimal separator is dot (`.`). I hope that you help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric characters(decimal and group separators) derived from `nls_numeric_characters` initialization parameter. Its default value,  derived from `nls_territory` initialization parameter, and default value of the `nls_territory` initialization parameter is operating system depended - derived from `NLS_LANG` environment variable or registry entry on Linux/Unix or Windows operating systems respectively.

You can override default value of `nls_numeric_characters` initialization parameter, depending o your needs, instance-wide, session-wide, or statement-wide. Here is a simple example:

```
/* current value:  , (comma) as decimal separator and 
                   . (period) as group separator and 
 */
SQL> show parameter nls_numeric_characters

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE 
------------------------------------ ----------- -------------
nls_numeric_characters               string      ,.  


SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 1.23 from dual union all
  3    select 234.43 from dual
  4  )
  5  select col
  6    from t1;

       COL  
----------          
      1,23        
    234,43
```

Session-wide:

```
/* set . (period) as decimal separator and 
       , (comma) as group separator */  
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters='.,';

Session altered.

SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 1.23 from dual union all
  3    select 234.43 from dual
  4  )
  5  select col 
  6    from t1;

       COL                       
----------                    
      1.23                   
    234.43
```

Statement-wide. In this situation we have to use `to_char()` function and provide number format model:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 1.23 from dual union all
  3    select 234.43 from dual
  4  )
  5  select to_char(col, '990d00', q'[nls_numeric_characters='.,']') as res
  6       , col
  7    from t1;


RES            COL   
------- ---------- 
   1.23       1,23 
 234.43     234,43
```